# Materion Bulk Metalic Glass

Tags: materials, metals

Materion sells 4 types of amorphous metal alloys,it cost huge amount of money,1000 dollar per kilogram.My question is,why would anybody choose it over lets say titanium 6al-4v?

Comment: Very generally: engineering is all about tradeoffs. Higher properties often cost more money.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're talking about their bulk metallic glass (BMG), aka amorphous glass forming alloys.

To quote [their site](https://materion.com/Products/Alloys/BulkMetallicGlass.aspx):

> **HIGH PERFORMANCE ALTERNATIVE TO TITANIUM**
>
> BMGs have strength-to-weight
> ratios more than twice those of titanium, magnesium and aluminum
> alloys.  Amorphous alloys typically have elastic limits that can be
> three times higher than crystalline metallic alloys and exhibit
> outstanding corrosion resistance due to their unique atomic structure
> and composition.
>
> **EASY TO FABRICATE**
>
> These amorphous alloys have the additional benefit
> of near net shape fabrication by injection molding and by a
> thermoplastic forming process, similar to plastics.

Whether or not that's worth the extra cost depends on your circumstance.